# Getting an error cannot find: POST http://localhost:8000/api/submit

Tags: reactjs, express, nodemailer

I have a simple form in React that submits a post request to /api/submit then my express server handles the post request as per my code snippet below, however I get an error that says: http://localhost:8000/api/submit 404 (Not Found). I feel like I missed something fundamental. Any suggestion is much appreciated.

I have my webpack proxy like so:

```
devServer: {
    contentBase: path.resolve('src'),
    hot: true,
    open: true,
    port: 8000,
    watchContentBase: true,
    historyApiFallback: true,
    proxy: {
      '/api': {
        target: 'http://localhost:4000',
        secure: false
      }
    }
  }
```

Client-side (Form):

```
formSubmit(e){
    e.preventDefault()

    axios.post('/api/submit', this.state.data)
    .then(() => {
        this.setState({ sent: true }, this.resetForm())
    })
    .catch(() => {
        console.log('Message not sent')
    })
}
```

Server-side:

```
app.post('/api/submit', (req, res) => {
  const data = req.body
  console.log(req.body)

  const smtpTransport = nodemailer.createTransport({
    service: 'gmail',
    port: 25,
    auth: {
      user: process.env.EMAIL,
      pass: process.env.PASS
    }
  })

  const mailOptions = {
    from: data.email,
    to: process.env.EMAIL,
    subject: 'Quote & Services',
    html: `<p>${data.name}</p>
    <p>${data.email}</p>
    <p>${data.message}</p>`
  }

  smtpTransport.sendMail(mailOptions,
    (error, res) => {
      if(error) {
        res.send(error)
      }else {
        res.send('Success')
      }
      smtpTransport.close()
    })
}) 

app.use(express.static(`${__dirname}/dist`))

app.get('/*', (req, res) => res.sendFile(`${__dirname}/dist/index.html`))

app.listen(process.env.PORT, () => console.log(`Express is serving the dist folder on port ${process.env.PORT}`))
```

Comment: did you try to reach the express server directly via port 4000 ?

Comment: yes I have, doesn't seem to work

Comment: is PORT environment variable correctly set ?

Comment: yes it is 4000.

Answer (score 0):

The `res` variable is overrided in `smtpTransport.sendMail` callback, you should name it differently